# Why won't iframe div scroll on iPad?

Tags: ipad, html, iframe, scroll

I have created an iframe within a div, and I just can't seem to get it to scroll (with either 1 or 2 fingers) on the iPad.  It works fine on an iPhone, but only when in Landscape mode.

The iframe is set to a height and width of 100% within the div and the div is set with overflow-y: auto and overflow-x: hidden.

For reference, the site is [www.cramondkirkbadminton.net](http://www.cramondkirkbadminton.net).

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Campbell

Comment: The overflow on the div shouldn't matter here as the iframe isn't bigger than the div. Do you see a scrollbar inside the iframe on the iPad?

Comment: The iPad doesn't show scrollbars, so it's a little tricky.  They do show up on all the desktop browsers tho.

Comment: As I don't have an iPad I can't help you out further, sorry. Maybe this behaviour is by design to not confuse users about where to put the finger to scroll.

Comment: It's not by design.  All the research I've done suggests it should work with 2 fingers if overflow is auto/scroll, altho I'm not sure if Apple changed that in iOS 6 to scroll with a single finger. :-/

Comment: As the overflow on the div is not relevant here, maybe you should explicitely set the overflow (auto/scroll) on the iframe's body element as this is the element that is scrolled in this case.

Comment: Ah, figured it out.  The div needed a style of **-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch**.  All good now. :)

PS.  I can't mark this as an answer as my reputation isn't high enough. :(

Comment: Glad to hear that. Maybe you can answer your own question to highlight how it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the style `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the iFrame, that should do it.